# How do I remove a validate class using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have some options for pricing using radio buttons.
When a user selects the radio button with no value my checkbox form must not be validated.
here is my code:

Options:

```
<input type="radio" name="pricing_option_rect" id="pricing_imp_rect1" checked="checked" value="100">100
<input type="radio" name="pricing_option_rect" id="pricing_imp_rect2" value="200">200
<input type="radio" name="pricing_option_rect" id="pricing_imp_rect3" value="300">300
<input type="radio" name="pricing_option_rect" id="pricing_imp_rect4" value="0" />0
```

Checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="check1" name="rectcat[]" class="{validate:{required:true, minlength:1, maxlength:5}}" />One
<input type="checkbox" value="check2" name="rectcat[]" />Two
<input type="checkbox" value="check3" name="rectcat[]" />Three
<input type="checkbox" value="check4" name="rectcat[]" />Four
<input type="checkbox" value="check5" name="rectcat[]" />Five
<input type="checkbox" value="check6" name="rectcat[]" />Six
<input type="checkbox" value="check7" name="rectcat[]" />Seven
<input type="checkbox" value="check8" name="rectcat[]" />Eight
<div class="container">
  <label for="rectcat[]" class="error">
    Please Select a Minimum of ONE and a Maximum of FIVE categories!
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change this:

```
class="{validate:{required:true, minlength:1, maxlength:5}}"
```

To this:

```
class="{validate:{required:'#pricing_imp_rect4:unchecked', minlength:1, maxlength:5}}"
```

`required` allows a depdency expression instead of just true.  In this case, it's only *required* if the `#pricing_imp_rect4` isn't checked.  [You can read more about the dependency expression option here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-expression).